# N body simulation in MATLAB for any N :

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot N Body problem by writing following code:

Expected output is ellipses with `0,0` as focus. But I am getting straight lines. Can anyone find out the mistake in code. Data used for simulation of 2 bodies is:

`Mass   1.99E+30    3.30E+23 x Velocity 0   0 y Velocity    0.00E+00    5.90E+04 x position 0   4.60E+10 y` `position`

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GravConst=6.67408e-11;
input='NBodyData.csv';
inputArray=csvread(input,0,1);
n=size(inputArray,2); %Number of Bodies

tIni =0; %Initial Time
tFinal =3600*24*365; %Final Time
deltaT=100; %(tFinal-tIni)/(tN-1); %Time Interval
tN=tFinal/deltaT;
X=zeros(n,tN); %Stores x coordinate at time t
Y=zeros(n,tN); %Stores y coordinate at time t
Vx=zeros(n,tN);%Stores x component of velocity
Vy=zeros(n,tN);%stores y component of velocity

mass(1:n,1)=(inputArray(1,:)') ; %'Column Vector to Store Mass of n bodies
Xini(1:n,1)=(inputArray(4,:)');  %'[0;0.3127;0.7307;1;1.4047;5.019;9.1954;18.6368;30.21;30.16];%Stores initial x coordinate
Yini(1:n,1)=(inputArray(5,:)');  %'[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];%Stores initial y coordinate

Vxini(1:n,1)=(inputArray(2,:)');%'Stores x component of initial velocity
Vyini(1:n,1)=(inputArray(3,:)');%'Stores y component of initial velocity
%r=zeros(n,n,tN);%Stores distance of masses


%--------------------------------------------------------
%Read Initial Position and Velocities
%--------------------------------------------------------
X(1:n,1)=Xini(1:n,1);
Y(1:n,1)=Yini(1:n,1);
Vx(1:n,1)=Vxini(1:n,1);
Vy(1:n,1)=Vyini(1:n,1);
fx=zeros(n,tN);
fy=zeros(n,tN);

%--------------------------------------------------------
%Iteration Starts
%--------------------------------------------------------

T=1
while(T<tN)

%Calculation of force
%

for i=1:n
    fx(i,T)=0;
    fy(i,T)=0;
    for j=1:n
        if i~=j
            fx(i,T)= fx(i,T)+ GravConst*mass(j,1)*(X(i,T)-X(j,T))/ ( (X(i,T)-X(j,T))^2+(Y(i,T)-Y(j,T))^2 )^1.5 ;
            fy(i,T)= fy(i,T)+ GravConst*mass(j,1)*(Y(i,T)-Y(j,T))/ ( (X(i,T)-X(j,T))^2+(Y(i,T)-Y(j,T))^2 )^1.5 ;
        end
    end
end

%----------------------------------------------------
%Calculate Velocities and Position at next time level
%----------------------------------------------------
for i=1:n            
    if(T==1)
        X(i,T+1)=X(i,T)+deltaT*Vx(i,1)+0.5*(deltaT*deltaT)*fx(i,T);
        Y(i,T+1)=X(i,T)+deltaT*Vy(i,1)+0.5*(deltaT*deltaT)*fy(i,T);
    else
        X(i,T+1)=2*X(i,T)-X(i,T-1)+(deltaT*deltaT)*fx(i,T);
        Y(i,T+1)=2*Y(i,T)-Y(i,T-1)+(deltaT*deltaT)*fy(i,T);
    end
end
T=T+1
end

%-----------------------------------------------------

X = (250/1e18)*X;
Y = (250/1e18)*Y;

close all;
figure(1) 
for i=1:n
     plot(X(i,:),Y(i,:));
     hold on;
end
figure(2)
plot(X(2,:),Y(2,:));
%--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you post runnable code? we can not jsut run that because you hace all the `inputArray` thing in the begginig. replace that for the parameters you used in this test

Comment: Without checking in detail. Maybe there is an error in the units. e.g. velocity too high. distance too high.    Try starting with Zero initial velocity. some acceleration should be seen in any case. then vary the initial velocity by in steps of order of magnitudes.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I have worked on the code and have executed successfully. There was mistake in calculation of force.